# Cant bind form to nested array properly in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to bind to a nested array to text inputs from a form. There are 6 blocks and each block contains 3 values. I have initially populated the array for mapping by using:

```
new Array(6).fill(['','',''])
```

and rendering the values using 2 loops. One for the 6 blocks and the other 3 values inside each block. The 3 values are the ones binding to the form. I refer to each of the inputs using the second parameter of the map function which is the index.

[image: Here is the view]

Here is the code in its entirety.

```
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardHeader,
  CardMedia,
  TextField,
  Grid,
  Typography,
  Button,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

export default function CreateEditQuestion() {
  const answerPack = new Array(6).fill(["", "", ""]);
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");
  const [answers, setAnswer] = useState(answerPack);
  const [TimeAllowed, setTimeAllowed] = useState(30);
  const [Score, setScore] = useState(1);
  const [Date, setDate] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleAnswerSet = (value, answerIndex, answerTextIndex) => {
    var updatedAnswer = answers;
    updatedAnswer[answerIndex][answerTextIndex] = value;
    setAnswer(updatedAnswer);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    let data = {
      question,
      answer_set: answers,
      time_allowed: TimeAllowed,
      score_value: Score,
      date: Date,
    };

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries({ question, Date })) {
      if (value.trim().length == 0) {
        alert(`${key} has not been filled in`);
        return false;
      }
    }

    axios
      .post(
        "https://localhost:8000/question",
        data
      )
      .then((resp) => {
        alert("Succesfully added Question");
        history.push("/question");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Create Question</h1>
      <Card elevation={1}>
        <CardHeader></CardHeader>
        <CardContent>
          <div>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label="Question"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setQuestion(e.target.value);
              }}
            ></TextField>
          </div>

          <Grid container direction={"row"} spacing={4}>
            {answers.map((answerTexts, i) => {
              return (
                <Grid key={i} item md={4} width={50}>
                  {answerTexts.map((text, j) => {
                    return (
                      <div style={{ width: "70%", marginTop: "30px" }}>
                        <TextField
                          fullWidth
                          label={`Answer ${i + 1} - ${j + 1}`}
                          onChange={(ev) => {
                            handleAnswerSet(ev.target.value, i, j);
                          }}
                          variant="outlined"
                        />

                        <br />
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </Grid>
              );
            })}
          </Grid>

          <Grid container direction={"row"} spacing={4}>
            <Grid item md={5} width={80}>
              <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom gutterTop>
                Extra Options
              </Typography>
              <TextField
                label={"Time Allowed : "}
                variant="outlined"
                defaultValue={TimeAllowed}
                onChange={(ev) => {
                  setTimeAllowed(ev.target.value);
                }}
              />{" "}
              &nbsp;
              <TextField
                label="Score"
                variant="outlined"
                defaultValue={Score}
                onChange={(ev) => {
                  setScore(ev.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={5} width={100}>
              <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom gutterTop>
                Question Date
              </Typography>

              <TextField
                type="date"
                onChange={(ev) => {
                  setDate(ev.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <div align="center">
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                handleSubmit();
              }}
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
            >
              Submit Question
            </Button>
          </div>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Problem:**
On each block, changing any value also changes all the other corresponding inputs in other blocks, so if the first input on the first block is changed, then all other first inputs in the other blocks also get changed,e.g(changing answer 1-1 also changes 2-1,3-1,4-1, etc). I could not trace why. Only the corresponding values should be changed

This is the function responsible for setting the values.

```
const handleAnswerSet = (value, answerIndex, answerTextIndex) => {
    var updatedAnswer = answers;
    updatedAnswer[answerIndex][answerTextIndex] = value;
    setAnswer(updatedAnswer);
  };
```

Comment: Hello, I wasn't able to find where you pass the value prop to each TextField, can you give some more info on that?

Comment: handleAnswerSet(ev.target.value) inside the j loop.

Comment: That is the `onChange` event handler, I was talking about `value`, as in `<input name="" value={} />`

Comment: @KevinHaxhi is it required?

Comment: Yes, you need to assign the specific values from the state that you update with your `onChange` event to the value prop of each input.